# How to check if a couchdb document exists (without retrieving it)?

Tags: couchdb

How can I just check if a document exists, mabye get the revision, but not make couchdb send the body of the document?

I remember I saw this explained somewhere but I cannot find it.

*Edit:* Iirc in the example you received only a http header with no data. The header indicated if present or not.

*Edit2:* Evan suggests to make a HEAD request (instead of GET). This answers my question.

*CouchDB sends an ETag Header for document requests. The ETag Header is simply the document's revision in quotes.*

Quoted from: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#ETags.2BAC8-Caching

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of performing a HTTP GET request, do a HTTP HEAD request. This will only return the headers and no content.  The returned status will tell you if the object exists.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that soon :) - karlthorwald - aka

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the cradle API?

Comment: Yes you can do this with cradle like so: 
db.head(id, function(err, opt1, opt2){
   if(opt2!='404') item exists do something
  })