# How to check if a couchdb document exists using python

Tags: python, couchdb

I was wondering if there is a way to check if a document with a particular ID exists in couchdb using couch python library. It seems that if I do this:

```
server = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')
db = server['tweets']
mytemp = db[MyDocId]
```

and the document doesn't exist, the code throws a "ResourceNotFound" exception.

I could just catch the exception and put my code in the exception handling portion, but it seems too dirty.

I was hoping there is a way to have an "if" statement that checks whether a document with a particular key exists or not.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a couchdb document exists (without retrieving it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831290/how-to-check-if-a-couchdb-document-exists-without-retrieving-it)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since I'm explicitly asking about the couch python library I can't really do the head http requests within that library (at least not in a clean way). I did read that solution before posting mine. Thanks for trying to help anyways! I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The database object mimics to dict api, so it's very simple and native to check for docs in database:

```
server = couchdb.Server('http://localhost:5984')
db = server['tweets']
if MyDocId in db:
  mytemp = db[MyDocId]

mytemp = db.get(MyDocId)
if mytemp is None:
  print "missed"
```

See [couchdb-python docs](http://pythonhosted.org/CouchDB/client.html#database) for more.